# Adding onMouseOver javascript to TextField

Tags: c#, javascript, itext, textfield

I want to add JavaScript to textfields in a PDF that are created using iTextSharp?

I've tried following code:

```
TextField field = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x, y - h, x + w, y), name);
field.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(bgcolor[0], bgcolor[1], bgcolor[2]);
field.BorderColor = new BaseColor(bordercolor[0], bordercolor[1], bordercolor[2]);
field.BorderWidth = border;
field.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID;
field.Text = text;

// PROBLEM:
//field.AddJavaScript = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.getField(\"Total_0\").value = ( this.getField(\"Quantity_0\").value * this.getField(\"Price_0\").value ) / this.getField(\"Multiplier_0\").value;", writer);

writer.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField());
```

The problem is:

`iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField` does not contain a definition for `AddJavaScript`.

So then how can I add JavaScript that activates when mouse cursor is over the text field or when the text field has been edited? My purpose is to calculate a value based on the values of other text fields using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an *additional action*. For instance: you have an *entry* action, defined using `PdfName.E` and an *exit* action, defined by `PdfName.X`. The entry action is triggered when the mouse enters the rectangle that defines the field; the exit action is triggered when the mouse exist the rectangle that defines the field.

In your code, you're skipping a step and that's probably why you didn't find the function you need:

```
PdfFormField ffield = field.GetTextField();
ffield.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.E, PdfAction("app.alert('action!')"));
writer.AddAnnotation(ffield);
```

This snippet will cause an alert to appear when the mouse enters the text field. Other options are `PdfName.D` (mouseDown), `PdfName.U` (mouseUp), `PdfName.K` (keystroke by user), `PdfName.V` (validate, because the value of the field has changed), etc.